# Why is my add-on panel´s content script no longer responding to port messages after changing contentUrl?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a Firefox add-on using the addon-sdk.

The add-on has one button that displays a panel on click. The panel has a content script running it. Now, I need the panel to look different depending on the user's current tab and occasionally show an external url.

So, the main.js script tracks the current tab of the user and sends messages to the content script using panel.port.emit() and the content script changes the HTML of the panel to match whatever is needed.

However, as I mentioned, some times the panel is just showing an external url, so I need to reset it back to its original url. This is my code:

```
function panelListMode(currentTab, data){

  panel.resize(350,300);

  //This is the line causing the trouble
  panel.contentURL = self.data.url("panel.html");

  console.log("sending message");
  panel.port.emit("generateList",data);
}
```

If I emit the message after changing the contentURL the content script does not seem to receive a thing. I now that specific line is the one causing the problem because if I comment it the content script receives the message.

Something tells me this is because the panel needs to load the DOM again and I need to wait until it is ready before the content script is able to do anything. But... aren't content scripts something apart from just included scripts?

As far as I am able to tell the panel has no "ready" event of sorts that I can listen to for emitting the message.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** After some experimentation I have been able to find some more. If I copy panel.html to the same directory as panel2.html and change my function so it goes:

```
function panelListMode(currentTab, data){

  panel.resize(350,300);

  //This is the line causing the trouble
  panel.contentURL = self.data.url("panel2.html");

  console.log("sending message");
  panel.port.emit("generateList",data);
}
```

The problem is gone. I have experimented a bit and it seems that when I try to change the contentURL to the html that is **already set** in the panel the content script stops working all together.

This is some really odd behavior... have I encountered a bug?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I am able to tell the panel has no "ready" event of sorts that I can listen to for emitting the message.

I think it does, at least internally it seems to but I'm not sure whether they're exposed.

But even if it doesn't you can simply fire your own port message from the content script once it has been attached and registered  its own listeners. Upon receiving that message in the addon you can then resume using the port on that side.

Comment: [The panel object does not seem to have that sort of ready event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Events). As for your solution, it is a good idea. I will give it a go. Do you know if changing the contentUrl de-attaches the content script? Do I need to add it again?

Comment: i think changing the URL just re-runs the content script on the new page

Comment: I tough as much so I added a console.log() at the start of the content script to see when is it run... and saw nothing after changing contentUrl

Comment: that seems odd and unexpected, but maybe you can attach a new one to the panel with the [content-worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/content_worker)

Comment: I have experimented and discovered some details about when is this happening. See my edit above. This is some really odd behavior. Have I encountered a bug?

Comment: possibly, have you checked whether it also happens in nightly?

Comment: I built a small add on just to test this behavior. Changing the contentURL of the panel reruns the content script **unless** you try setting the contentURL to whatever is already set. If you do, the content script stops and is never rerun again. Happens in nightly too. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: yes, you probably should report it, especially since you have a reduced test-case. in the meantime you can probably can work around it by only setting the url when it actually changes