# Firefox extension: Not executing panel.port.emit inside panel.port.on in addon js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

I am new on Firefox addon. I am trying to execute Panel's port.emit which reside in port.on. I am using firefox browser 39.0.3.

Code as follows:

**Main.js**

```
 var panel = panels.Panel({
        contentURL: contentUrl
        width: 354,
        height: 435,
        onHide: handleHide,
        contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("scripts/Lib/jquery.min.js"), self.data.url("scripts/common.js")]
    });

//Working..
    panel.port.on('getAllUserSites', function(data) {
        panel.port.emit("sendAllUserSites", null); //Not working
    });
```

**common.js**

```
 var lnkGetSite = document.getElementById('lnkAllUserSites');
    lnkGetSite.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        self.port.emit('getAllUserSites', null); //Working..
    }, false);

    self.port.on("sendAllUserSites", function (data) {
        console.log('sendAllUserSites')
    });
```

Comment: Your code flow should be `click` -> `self.port.emit` -> `panel.port.on` -> `panel.port.emit` -> `self.port.on` - you've detemined that the second last part  isn't firing (panel.port.emit), what about the three steps before that? is that happening?

Comment: The code flow is same as you have suggested. Click -> self.port.emit -> panel.port.on. After that panel.port.emit is not firing, that is calling self.port.on("sendAllUserSites", function (data) {
    console.log('sendAllUserSites')
});

Comment: I'm fully aware what the flow is - I'm wonderring how you've determined where the problem is ..  can you say the click event is firing, the self.port.emit is working, the panel.port.on is working ...

Comment: Yes, Click and self.port.emit is working. I have used console.log('success') to verify that panel.port.on is firing. After that, it try to call  panel.port.emit("sendAllUserSites", null); but its not logging console.log('sendAllUserSites') inside self.port.on. That means panel.port.emit not working... I hope I am able to give you explanation..

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to know that you've checked that ... of course, all you have  (and can) confirm is that `self.port.on` is not being run, you can't infer from that that panel.port.emit isn't working :p

Comment: So what is the solution to call panel.port.emit ??

Comment: If I put panel.port.emit inside panel.on('show', function() {
   panel.port.emit("sendAllUserSites", null);
}); its working fine. Then what is the issue inside panel.port.on??

Comment: I think this is the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953220/why-is-my-add-on-panel%C2%B4s-content-script-no-longer-responding-to-port-messages-af?rq=1